# HTML5 Video Play buttons not centering on IOS Safari

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video, html5-video

I am having an issue with IOS HTML5 Video player not centering the videos on page load. Once a video is selected, all of the videos play icons become centered. Has anyone had this issue before? Is there a way to hide the play button that sits on top of IOS HTML5 videos?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you want to say I can't understand the problem clearly.

Comment: you want to centre the video button or else hide that button. can you explain clearly?